# Add price beside Woocommerce Force Sells

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, price

Woocommerce Force Sells by default only lists the product titles. I need them to also show the product price in brackets beside each title. You can see it [**here**](http://ahbc.space/birth-pools/inflatable-birth-pool-hire/) like in this screenshot:

[image]

But it should be:

- Birth Pool Hire Bond ($50.00)
- Birth Pool Liner ($33.00)

Is there a filter I can use so that Force Sells puts the prices beside items? Barring that, how can I alter the Force Sells code so that it also outputs price as well?

This is the part of the Force Sells code that outputs the items under the add to cart box on single product pages:

```
    /**
     * Displays information of what linked products that will get added when current
     * product is added to cart.
     */
    public function show_force_sell_products() {
        global $post;

        $product_ids = $this->get_force_sell_ids( $post->ID, array( 'normal', 'synced' ) );
        $titles      = array();

        // Make sure the products still exist and don't display duplicates.
        foreach( array_values( array_unique( $product_ids ) ) as $key => $product_id ) {
            $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

            if ( $product && $product->exists() && 'trash' !== $product->get_status() ) {
                $titles[] = version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '>=' ) ? $product->get_title() : get_the_title( $product_id );
            }
        }

        if ( ! empty( $titles ) ) {
            echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
            echo '<div class="wc-force-sells">';
            echo '<p>' . __( 'This will also add the following products to your cart:', 'woocommerce-force-sells' ) . '</p>';
            echo '<ul>';

            foreach ( $titles as $title ) {
                echo '<li>' . $title . '</li>';
            }

            echo '</ul></div>';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_title', 'custom_product_title', 20, 2 );
function custom_product_title( $name, $product ) {
    // Only in single product pages
    if( ! is_product() ) return $name;

    // The product name + the product formatted price
    return $name . ' (' . wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product ) ) . ')';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: Great, thank you!! :)
I just had to remove the underscore from `$name . ' ('...` otherwise it showed up as _($33.00).

Comment: @RoseFisher Yes a little minor mistake… removed too now.

Comment: That didn't work for me