# Conditionally alter multiple specifics products prices in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, woocommerce-bookings

I am using the code from here: [Conditionally alter specific product price in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594920/conditionally-alter-specific-product-price-in-woocommerce) to increase the price of a specific product by $10 except on product pages from a certain category and if the cart contains anything from that category.

However now I have more than one product that I need to increase the price of. I tried altering line 7:

```
if( $product->get_id() != 87 ) return $price_html;
```

to something like

```
if( $product->get_id() != 87 || $product->get_id() != 2799 ) return $price_html;
```

to target product 87 or 2799 but it just breaks the code and even product 87 no longer displays as $10 more. I have tried variations on || and or but nothing I do works.

Help much appreciated :)

Comment: Above code snippet looks good. Maybe something else is affecting it. Can you share the entire code block so we can debug it?

Answer (score 2):

For multiple product IDs, instead of using something like:

```
add_filter( 'some_hook', 'some_function' );
function some_function( $price_html, $product ){
    if( $product->get_id() != 87 || $product->get_id() != 2799 ) return $price_html;

    // The function code 

    return $price_html; // at the end
}
```

You will use something like:

```
add_filter( 'some_hook', 'some_function' );
function some_function( $price_html, $product ){
    if( in_array( $product->get_id(), array( 87, 2799 ) ) ){

        // The function code 

    }

    return $price_html; // at the end
}
```

And it will work for an array of multiple products

Comment: Thanks! Changing line 7 to `if( ! in_array( $product->get_id(), array( 87, 2799 ) ) ) return $price_html; // Exit` works great!

Answer (score 0):

Your *if* condition doesn't makes sense because it will always return true. Try to replace *or* with *and*:

```
if( $product->get_id() != 87 && $product->get_id() != 2799 ) return $price_html;
```

Comment: Thanks @IvnH My coding fortes lie outside PHP so it's been quite the learning curve for me to understand logic. I get the differences now :)